# how rails determines which form field had an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, field

i am trying to validate my form on the client side via js. I have nested fields in my form and i need to know, which field hat the error since there can be more fields of the same type, e.g. fon number. Inside the error of the model, it just says, which 'type' of field had the error like 'person.fon' but not which of the fon fields. I use the nested_form gem so every field has a unique id

How does rails determines exactly, which field had the error? When i use the standard form validation, the right fields are wrapped in the error div.

thats how rails does it

[image]

with @model.errors i just get the info, that one of the fields(fon, email, etc.) had an error, but not which one.

Comment: is `fon` a model and you have its attributes nested in person form?

Comment: fon is a model, but i only crud it via the nested form through my person model

Answer (score 0):

You only need to see in your LOGS and see what is the incorrect form it.
After that you will see what line is wrong.

Comment: the form is correct, i need the exact field, which had an validation error

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have instance variable `@person` available in you views, then you can get errors using `@person.fon.errors`

You can see docs for the errors object you get back from rails model here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html

Comment: i don't need only the error, i need the id of the form field, where the error occurred. some how that must be possible, since rails is wrapping the form fields with the error div

Comment: `@person.fon.errors` will return errors object that will have fields and messages for given fields that failed. rails uses field name as ids for html so you get ids from there. I updated answer with link to docs  for error object you get from rails. please read and get familiar to it. it has all the information you need.

Comment: I think that is not working for me. The IDs of my form fields look like this: person_fons_attributes_0_number,person_fons_attributes_1_number and differ only by the number inside the ID. Now the error messages contain the form field like this: :"fons.number"=>["can't be blank"].

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be buried deep within [ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/44a9aedd7b8d65517b15bbbb7729f3f16991e23f/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1185).  Though, not sure how this can be used efficiently yet.